# Cannot display attachments in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attachments

I'm trying to learn ArcGIS Pro 1.4, and with a little bit of pain I was progressing till today in which I cannot make my previous hyperlinks get ready in ArcGIS Pro. I think enabling attachments in first place and configure pop-ups afterwards might the be the right workflow to follow, correct?

I have reviewed the post: [Work with file attachments](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/edit-file-attachments.htm), but it hasn't helped me so far with this issue.

These are the steps I have followed so far:

i.e.: I have a point feature class, with some of the locations having associated files which I want to convert into attachments.

1. Analysis tab -> Tools -> Geoprocessing pane: [Enable Attachments](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/enable-attachments.htm) on the feature class that I want it to have hyperlinks functionality enabled.

[image: Enable attachments]

This operation went well:

[image: Results okay]

After doing this a relationship class and a table have been created in my geodatabase, OK.

[image: ArcCatalog view]

2. Then, If I go the Attributes panel, Attachments, click +Add, when I pick up the file, it pop-ups an error:

[image: ArcPro error]

What am I missing?

Comment: What parameter values did you supply to those two tools?  Have you reviewed the [Work with file attachments](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/edit-file-attachments.htm) documentation?

Comment: (Edite above). The tools didn't raise any error, actually ArcPro raised a success message after running them every time, but still the attachments capability is not enable at all in my software.

Comment: What parameter values did you supply to those two tools?

Comment: I've attached a few screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Match table, THEN add attachments.